# Type 'ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type '"json

Tags: angular

I am currently upgrading my angular application to angular 7. Getting the following error. Just to let you know I am using httpclient. Not sure what the problem is.

Type 'ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type '"json. The error is at the line responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer

```
previewDocument(id: number) {
        //var pars = new URLSearchParams();
        let pars = new HttpParams();
        pars.set('id', id.toString());
        return this.http.get(this.config.api.previewDocument, { search: pars, withCredentials: true,  responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`ResponseContentType` is deprecated. If you request non JSON data check the documentation for an example [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data).

> The following types are available: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' |
>   'text'

I assume for your case you would use `responseType: 'arraybuffer'`.

Comment: I have seen the example so do you mean it will be like this return this.http.get(this.config.api.previewDocument, { params: pars, withCredentials: true,  responseType: 'arraybuffer' });

Comment: I assume there is no enum

Comment: Yes, as you wrote it in your comment. Did it work for you?

Comment: could you please suggest, from where I need to import responseType?